# pythonpath and omniORB

Tags: python

In README file of omniORBpy-3.4 is written that I have to set PYTHONPATH as

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%TOP%\lib\python;%TOP%\lib\x86_win32
```

Where %TOP% is the top-level omniORBpy directory. (Windows machine)

I have done that and reboot my machine but when I try to run *.py files which have a line like

```
import omniORB
```

it gives me an error that no such module omniORB.
What I should do?

Comment: Where have you set the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I have typed a command in console like this
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\Python2.7;C:\Program Files\Python2.7\DLLs;C:\Program Files\Python2.7\Lib;C:\Program Files\omniORBpy-3.4\lib\python;C:\Program Files\omniORBpy-3.4\lib\x86_win32

Comment: And if you run in the same cmd your python code, it fails with ImportError? You can set `PYTHONPATH` in `(My )Computer->Properties->Advanced->Env vars` to make it system-wide.

Comment: @khachik See my comment on Dirk's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find that the README file of omniORBpy says that `TOP` must be set to the "the root of your omniORB tree" and *not* omniORBpy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure here, but I don't think, that changes made to the environment via a batch script will persist across reboots. Try setting the variable via the Workstation properties (sorry, I have no Windows machine at hand, and cannot give more than a few general directions):

Right click on the Workstation icon on your desktop. 
Select "Manage..." (I think it was)

Somewhere in the advanced settings, you can modify environment variables (no need to reboot, but you may have to fire up a new CMD.EXE afterwards, as running apps might not get the change).

Alternatively, you can create a small batch script to start you application, and make it modify the environment before the application is started (I think, this is, what the README actually suggests)

Comment: I have tried that(Right click on workstation...) but the result is the same as I've described in the comment to my question